# FINANCIAL YEAR CLOSE

Tags: sql, informix

I have a SQL query which was initially this-

```
DELETE FROM table_1
WHERE column_1 IN (  SELECT column_1 FROM table_2 WHERE 
column_3 < CURRENT - INTERVAL(N) MONTH TO MONTH)
```

Now my advisory has told to use Financial Close Year instead of CURRENT like:

```
DELETE FROM table_1
WHERE column_1 IN (  SELECT column_1 FROM table_2 WHERE 
column_3 < FINANCIAL YEAR CLOSE - INTERVAL(N) MONTH TO MONTH)
```

FINANCIAL YEAR CLOSE being March End.

I have no idea as to how I should incorporate the changes.

Comment: I am using sql server from teraterm application

Comment: CURRENT was working fine..i only need the logic for FINANCIAL YEAR CLOSE

Comment: Alright but could you help me with this?

Comment: @user8367639 Can you please edit your question and supply the appropriate tags for the technologies involved?

Comment: I would have if I knew which one is the correct tag, all I can say is I am using server from Teraterm application where if i give dbaccess <dbname> it will go to SQL query mode... I am new to coding, sorry

Comment: What does column 3 have in it, and what is the data type?

Comment: I can say it has  bill_dates/invoice_dates/cheque_dates

Comment: thats a start. And the datatype? It doesn't seem like you are the right person for this job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since FINANCIAL YEAR CLOSE can be different from one company to another it is not a built in function and has to be calculated manually.

You need to use CURRENT and extract the year part from that date and create a new date from [current year]-03-31 and use that in your query.

Some googling makes me think this is an Informix database from IBM.

Comment: Actually after the part where- YEAR=`date +%Y`   to put into the [current year]-03-31

Comment: What if I give it on 12-01-2018  or 12-02-2018...Jan & Feb will be logical error

Answer (score 1):

You could always use TO_DATE() with a specific mask, something like:

```
$dbaccess stores7 -
Database selected.

> SELECT (TO_DATE("2018-03-01","%Y-%m-%d") - INTERVAL (1) MONTH TO MONTH) FROM TABLE(SET{1});
(constant)
2018-02-01 00:00:00.00000
1 row(s) retrieved.
>
Database closed.
$
```

Whatever you put as a date string is really up to you ;)