# 1260: It is not possible to convert between the specified types

Tags: sql, casting, informix

I have a query-

```
DELETE FROM invoice
WHERE inv_date <  2018-03-31 - INTERVAL(72) MONTH TO MONTH)
```

when I execute I get an error stating-

**1260: It is not possible to convert between the specified types.**

What's wrong with "2018-03-31"? how should I write so that I can execute and get results?

Comment: `2018-03-31` is an integer with the value of 1984 (2018 minus 3 minus 31). See the manual for details: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_155.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317734/1260-it-is-not-possible-to-convert-between-the-specified-types#comment85639332_49317734), you need to use a DATETIME literal, not a series of integer subtractions:

```
DELETE FROM invoice
 WHERE inv_date <  DATETIME(2018-03-31) YEAR TO DAY - INTERVAL(72) MONTH TO MONTH
```

Or:

```
DELETE FROM invoice
 WHERE inv_date <  DATETIME(2018-03-31) YEAR TO DAY - 72 UNITS MONTH
```

In standard SQL, you might write:

```
DELETE FROM invoice
 WHERE inv_date <  DATE '2018-03-31' - INTERVAL '72' MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure we already answer this one here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49302163/7761106

As a horse with no name ;) suggested, always check the manual first